# Urllib3 connection error in Python using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have written a program that scrapes tweets and puts them in a MySQL server using python 3.5 and Tweepy 3.7. This program ran fine without any problems for a day before I got the error below.

I haven't been able to try to fix it since im not sure what the error means. It doesn't really reference any particular part of the code except for line 357 which is the Tweepy stream function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 563, in _readinto_chunked
n = self._safe_readinto(mvb)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 610, in _safe_readinto
raise IncompleteRead(bytes(mvb[0:total_bytes]), len(b))
    http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read, 512 more expected)

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
yield
      File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 384, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
      File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 433, in read
n = self.readinto(b)
      File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 463, in readinto
return self._readinto_chunked(b)
      File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\http\client.py", line 574, in _readinto_chunked
raise IncompleteRead(bytes(b[0:total_bytes]))
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dmnte/PycharmProjects/sql_prac/tweepy_stream_secinfo.py", line 357, in <module>
tweepy_stream.filter(track=['phishing'.......])
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 453, in filter
self._start(is_async)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 368, in _start
self._run()
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 300, in _run
six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 269, in _run
self._read_loop(resp)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 319, in _read_loop
line = buf.read_line()
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 181, in read_line
self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 401, in read
raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\dmnte\PycharmProjects\cabby\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 320, in _error_catcher
raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

Where can I start looking to how to fix this error ?

Comment: Are you maintaining the same http connection for the entire day? Did your network fail at the time of this backtrace? Let this be a lesson in handling exception handling. Was this twitter you where connected to? Maybe they just shutdown your connection.

Comment: I wasnt at the computer when it stopped so I cant answer most of those. I just wanted to confirm that it wasnt on error with my code.

Comment: Its most likely not an error with your code. If you thought it was, you should of included the code in the question. We're not psychic :-)